# An orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Can anyone give me some hint on the following problem **without using any knowledge about complex analysis or Fourier analysis**? Thanks a lot!

Consider the Hilbert space 
$$\mathscr{H}:=\bigg\{f\text{ is Lebesgue measurable}\,\bigg|\,\int_\mathbb{R}|\,f(x)\,|^2 \exp\bigg(-\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg)\,\mathrm{d}x<\infty\bigg\}.$$

Show that $\{H_n/\|H_n\|\}_{n\ge 0}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathscr{H}$, where $\{H_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the sequence of Hermite Polynomials.

I planned to attack this problem in the following way (orthogonality and modular $1$ are not problems. The only problem is completeness): Let $f\in\mathscr{H}$ such that $\langle f, H_n\rangle=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and then show that $f$ is indeed the zero function. But I do not finger out the trick to nail the last step...